# Calling function defined in exe

Tags: python

I need to know a way to call a function defined in the exe from a python script.
I know how to call entire exe from py file.

Answer (score 7):

Unless your EXE is a COM object, or specifically exports certain functions like a dll does, then this is not possible.

For the COM method take a look at these resources:

- [Python Programming On Win32](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565926219/) book, by Mark Hammond and Andy Robinson.
- [COM and Python](http://techarttiki.blogspot.com/2008/03/calling-python-from-maxscript.html) quick start on learning COM with python

For the exported functions like a dll method, please use python's win32 module along with the Win32 API LoadLibrary and related functions.

**If you have access to the EXE's source code:**

If you have access to the source code of this EXE though, you should define command line arguments and tie that into calling the function you want to call.  In this case you can use the python *os.system* call to start your application or *subprocess.call()*.

Comment: The subprocess module is much preferred over os.system. I know, it's a trivial complaint, but I'm a person of trivialities.

Comment: The ctypes module can also be used for calling functions from a dll, it's easy, crossplatform and it's in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is for windows. But you can treat an exe like a dll (if functions are exported). And they can be used by other programs.