# Execute Function from Compiled Executable

Tags: c++, c

I would like to be able to call a function in a compiled executable with my own parameters. For example, the function offset could be 0x00402120 and it accepts 2 parameters. The function I would like to call is simple in nature and does not call any library functions, so I don't need to worry about importing libraries and trying to fix up the library addresses.

In the past, I have written debugger scripts to perform this action, but I would rather not have to load the executable into a debugger.

Any suggestions would be great. I would prefer to implement this in C or C++.

Comment: Call a function from where?

Comment: This is ill-advised, unless you're trying to create some warez.  There's almost certainly a better way to do this, if your use case is legitimate.

Comment: Is that function exported? I mean, can you see it in tools like DLL Export Viewer? http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html

Comment: - I would like to call the function from another application.
- Unfortunately the function is not exported, it's not a DLL

Comment: OK, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598569/calling-function-defined-in-exe "Unless your EXE is a COM object, or specifically exports certain functions like a dll does, then this is not possible."

Comment: Another option I have thought of is to extract the disassembly for the function and inline the assembly with C code. I was just wondering if anyone knew of another way to do this.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487165/is-it-possible-to-call-a-non-exported-function-that-resides-in-an-exe

Comment: What's the issue with debugger scripts? Would it be ok to use a library? I guess that the diffucult parts are separated into a library, in gdb, so you may be able to use that.

Answer (score 3):

Here, I have made the following.

This is my C++ code:

```
#include<iostream>

void foo(int x) {
  std::cout<<"calling foo("<<x<<")"<<std::endl;
}

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

This is how I compile it:

```
g++ program.cpp -o program -O0
```

This is how I determine the name of the `foo` function:

```
[myprompt ~] nm program
0000000100001090 S _NXArgc
0000000100001098 S _NXArgv
0000000100000e70 t __GLOBAL__sub_I_program.cpp
0000000100000dcc T __Z3fooi
0000000100000e28 t __Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii
                 U __ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
                 U __ZNSolsEi
                 U __ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
                 U __ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
                 U __ZSt4cout
                 U __ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
0000000100001088 s __ZStL8__ioinit
                 U __ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
                 U ___cxa_atexit
00000001000010a8 S ___progname
0000000100000000 T __mh_execute_header
00000001000010a0 S _environ
                 U _exit
0000000100000e1d T _main
0000000100001000 s _pvars
                 U dyld_stub_binder
0000000100000d90 T start
```

And this is how I call the `foo` function (I do it from Python because I'm lazy, but you could do this using any other program which allows you load libraries).

```
import ctypes
program = ctypes.CDLL("./program")
program._Z3fooi(ctypes.c_int(2))
```

Run:

```
[myprompt ~] python callprogram.py
calling foo(2)
```

This is not portable (the name mangling may vary from compiler to compiler; from platform to platform). It works for me. But I never need to do this, so I wonder how useful can it be.

Answer (score 0):

The big problem is that programs may not execute at the same address each time.  Thus you would have to know the offset of the function within the executable.

Another issue:  The OS may "page" out functions of an executable that are not used and read them into memory on-demand.  And only the OS will know where they are placed.

You may be able to use to tools to extract the function out of the executable and put into a file.  But the function may have dependencies elsewhere in the file.  Those would need to be extracted and the addresses readjusted.  Possible, but not suggested.